# compatibleDimensions in AdSense Metadata

Tags: api, google-api, adsense, adsense-api

`compatibleDimensions` has the structure of the following:

```
 "kind": "adsense#reportingMetadataEntry",
 "id": "EXAMPLE_DIMENSION",
 "compatibleDimensions": [
   "1",
   "2",
   "4",
   ...
 ],
```

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/metadata

What does this mean by the numbers? Does it mean index?
I can't find anything that mentions about this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/metadata under "Understanding dimension compatibility"

> The `compatibleDimensions` field shows a list where each item is an integer representing a group of compatible dimensions. As there is no one-to-one relation between compatible dimensions, they are represented as groups.